# SignalR - Forever Frame in IE stops working after a few minutes of being idle

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, comet, signalr

I am using SignalR in IE9 and, unfortunately, it has to degrade to using the forever frame connection.

I have spent some time looking at this with the Developer Tools in IE. I can see the  callbacks loading into the dynamically inserted IFrame, and they call the receive function in the SignalR plugin. However after about 20/30 of these it just stops responding - I can no longer call client script from the server.

I'm guessing that the IFrame load is finally timing out, but there appear to be no events raised for this, so I cannot force a reconnect.

Has anyone managed to get a robust SignalR connection working in IE?

Thanks :)

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using? I used to observe this all the time in IE9 in older versions of SignalR, but I never see it anymore as of like 0.5.

Comment: I also see this on IE9 with 0.5.3 on JabbR, had to switch to longPolling there to make it reliable. Wasn't able to find out exactly what is going on yet.

Comment: @DrewMarsh I am using the newest version on NuGet - 0.5.3

Answer (score 9):

We had an issue where the Javascript on a website would stop working, specifically we noted this in that Ajax calls would not work. After some investigation we found that SignalR was the reason for the crash, and we found this post about Forever Frames. We tried removing Forever Frames support in SignalR with the following code in the clients JavaScript:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'serverSentEvents', 'longPolling'] });
```

Thus only supporting 'webSockets', 'serverSentEvents', 'longPolling'.

Comment: Or you can set a timeout after a 1-2 minutes, so client need to reconnect.

Comment: Crash? What does crash mean in this context

Comment: Edited post for precision. JavaScipt crashes: that is other Ajax calls would stop working (Specifically an action that would return a partial view in an Ajax call would instead redirected to a new page).

Comment: I was having this issue in IE11, but in my case the part that should receive the updates was in an iframe itself (with `allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms` all enabled). Switching ForeverFrame off was the solution!

Comment: Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1963#issuecomment-20171833) Github issue this was fixed in jQuery 1.10.1.

The problem was introduced in 1.9.x and fixed on 1.10.1.

Running with JQuery 1.8.1 it seems to work too.

Solution: Update jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I saw this happening, I actually had rogue, zombie IE9 processes running in the background. They didn't even have a window associated with them. So, I would go and kill those zombies off and relaunch a new instance of IE and not have a problem for a long time until whatever anamoly causes the issue happened again.

Sounds crazy I know, but I spent a long time explaining to David Fowler the symptoms of the problem and how I could never see any reason for the iFrame to magically stop firing the event to have the transport know to start the next iFrame session. The SignalR messages themselves always terminated the logical message stream properly, the onreadystatechange event would simply stop firing.

Comment: So currently, there is no fix for this issue right now?  besides killing off old ie9 tasks in your task manager? =/ I also get same problem in Safari

Comment: The problem that I was experiencing, no... it was something with the way the iframe worked within IE that it would just stop firing ready state change events back to the main window until I killed the bad IE process.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in document ready event and all of your iframe problems would be solved:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'serverSentEvents', 'longPolling'] });
```