# ie9 signalR stops working after a while

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Weird problem, it seems like after a while in my application ie9 browsers stop getting signalR messages, but they do not disconnect from the hub because my disconnect task was not run.  My code just cant seem to call any of the ie9 client's js functions.  Anyone know why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

There are several reports of this already on StackOverflow. You can see my answer to another question about this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268246/signalr-forever-frame-in-ie-stops-working-after-a-few-minutes-of-being-idle).

If you need more assistance I recommend opening an issue with the [SignalR project on GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues?state=open).